# SendGrid - It's like it does not send email to the customer

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, sendgrid

It's like I have contact Sendrid to hear about how I may not send email.

That's because I need a username and password to be able to do that.

*Sendgrid say on Twitter (PM)*

> For sending mail through SMTP, you will want to set your host to http://smtp.sendgrid.net . You can then use port 587, 2525 or 25 for TLS connections, and can use either your SendGrid username/password for authentication, or an API key generated on your account.

Code:

```
var resultMail = await _viewRenderService.RenderToStringAsync("~/Views/Templates/NewPassword.cshtml", viewModel);

var api = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("azure_xxxxxxx@azure.com");
var client = new SendGridClient(api);
var from = new EmailAddress("hello@hello.com", "J. Petersen");
var to = new EmailAddress("test@test.com", "Test");
var plainTextContent = Regex.Replace(resultMail, "<[^>]*>", "");
var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, title, plainTextContent: plainTextContent,
                        htmlContent: null);

var resulta = client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

I have looked at [Documentation on Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v3_Mail/csharp.html), and I do not think I'll find that you need to use username and password and port.

It is built in .net core 2.0 - Problems are how can I add my username and password and port to this?

Comment: maybe you should await on the last call

Comment: its not work, i have try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using the API not SMTP, Here is the standard smtp

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage
{
    From = new MailAddress("support@bla.net"),
    Subject = "Hello World",
    Body = "Test email from Send Grid SMTP Settings"
};

mailMessage.To.Add("someone@somehwere.net");

var smtpClient = new SmtpClient
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Your-Username@azure.com", "Your-Password"),
    Host = "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    Port = 587
};

smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```